# Object wont get created?

Tags: javascript, object, compiler-errors, undefined, instantiation

I am making a snake game but when I try and instantiate my snake object I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
drawSnake();    

}
```

This is where I instantiate the snake object and draw it and where i get the error more specifically line 13.

```
function drawSnake(){
    var Snake = new Snake(250,250,-1,0);
    Snake.create();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    for(i=Snake.snakeBlock.length(); i>=0;i--){
        var s = Snake.snakeBlock[i].block;
        ctx.fillRect(s.xPos,s.xPos,s.height,s.width);
    }
}    

function Block(x,y,w,h){
    var xPos = x;
    var yPos = y;
    var width = w;
    var height = h;
}
```

This is where I define the snake object yet I still get an error.

```
function Snake(x,y,dY,dX){
    var snakeBlock = [];
    var length = 20;
    var xPos = x;
    var yPos = y;
    var dirX = dX;
    var dirX = dY;
    Snake.prototype.create = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        snakeBlock.push(new Block((xPos-(i*10))*dirX, (yPos-(i*10))*dirY,10,10));
    };
}
}
```

Is there something that I am ignoring in the creation of objects as I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: For more info about constructor functions and prototype the following answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var Snake = new Snake(250,250,-1,0);
> ```

Are you trying to overwrite the `Snake` constructor here? Anyway, the [declaration of the local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is *shadowing* the global `Snake` constructor reference, and `Snake` is `undefined` when you try to call it. Use a different variable name - usually instance names are lowercased:

```
var snake = new Snake(250, 250, -1, 0);
```

> ```
> for(i=Snake.snakeBlock.length(); i>=0;i--){
> ```

- use a local variable: `var i`
- `.length` is indeed not a function: [it is a plain, numeric property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).
- `snakeBlock` is a local variable in the `Snake` constructor, not a property.

> ```
>     var s = Snake.snakeBlock[i].block;
> ```

`snakeBlock[i]` does already reference the `Block` instance you put there. It does not have a `.block` property.

> ```
>     var snakeBlock = [];
> ```

As already mentioned, this does declare a local variable. You want to access it from the outside, though (in prototype methods, in your `drawSnake` call), so you should create a property instead:

```
this.snakeBlock = [];
```

Read more on the differences in [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572).

> ```
>     Snake.prototype.create = function(){
> ```

Never put an assignment to the prototype inside the constructor! Your indentation is also screwed up.

> ```
> snakeBlock.push(…)
> ```

Now, access it as a property:

```
this.snakeBlock.push(…)
```

Also see [@MattWay's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62VDC/) for a fixed up version :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things wrong with the code you have pasted. I have created a really quick fiddle, and adjusted your code so that it doesn't give errors (although it's likely not the best way to write it anyway).

http://jsfiddle.net/62VDC/

Some of the things I found were related to not using `this`. Trying to use a variable name `Snake` at the same time as an object named `Snake`. Referencing things like `snakeBlock[i].block` when there is no `block` component. Using `length()`, when you should simply use `.length`. Putting `prototype` functions inside the construtor.

If you need more help, you might have to elaborate.